# Worklight 6.1 installation failed with DB2 10.5, WAS 8.5

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8

I am installing the Worklight server 6.1 with the DB2 10.5, but almost at the last step the installation failed leaving the error below.  Can you please explain what is wrong?
OS 64 bit Redhat, with java 1.6

Bellow is the content of "failed-install.log"

```
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: /opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/jre_6.0.0.sr9_20110208_03/jre
Detected OS: Linux

BUILD FAILED
/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/post-install.xml:335: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/post-install.xml:2257: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/post-install.xml:2610: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/post-install.xml:5582: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1666, SQLSTATE=42613, SQLERRMC=Generated column, DRIVER=3.66.46
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:741)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.c(oo.java:2763)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.d(oo.java:2751)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.b(oo.java:2134)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.i(ab.java:226)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.c(ab.java:48)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.o.b(o.java:38)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.tb.h(tb.java:124)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.hb(oo.java:2129)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.a(oo.java:3284)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.e(oo.java:1085)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.execute(oo.java:1064)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execSQL(SQLExec.java:775)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.runStatements(SQLExec.java:745)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec$Transaction.runTransaction(SQLExec.java:1055)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec$Transaction.access$000(SQLExec.java:985)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:653)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 17 seconds
```

Comment: When you ran Installation manager, was the APPCNTR database already created? I hit an issue in WL6.0 where installing via installation manager would fail if you didn't let the WL installer create the APPCNTR DB for you (contrary to what the installer implies with the "already setup" check)

Comment: Its a fresh DB2 instance, Installation manager only created APPCNTR  database on its own

Comment: do we have to create any database tables manually, before we proceed with installation manager's installation?

Comment: Do you think iam using the wrong JDBC version?

Comment: Wrong JDBC version may be possible, but if you're starting with a fresh DB2 instance, totally clean, then my suggestion on a potential problem flies out the window. Still thinking on this one, as I haven't seen this issue before. Always something new it seems -_-

Comment: Did you check thru all the steps listed here? http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_ov_server_install.html

Comment: Are you running script for creating database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables of Application Center use the 'Generated By' feature. Have you entered a setting in your database that is incompatible with that feature ?
This description of the error message you have shows that a setting DFT_TABLE_ORG could be the cause of the error you experiment:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc%2Fdoc%2Fmsql01666n.html